# Javascript Runtime Error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference of dynamically created Textboxes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm creating some textboxes in `ASP.NET C#` Code-Behind and trying to style them using a simple `javascript`, which I also want to call from Code-Behind.

The Problem is that I'm getting a `Javascript` Runtime Error. The error is `"0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference"`

#### My ".aspx" page is as follows:

```
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function call_me(x) {
      var txtbox = document.getElementById(x);
      txtbox.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      txtbox.style.color = 'yellow';
    }

  </script>

</head> 

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>
```

#### My "C# Code-Behind" file is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    //textbox creation
    TextBox tx = new TextBox();
    tx.ID = "textbox" + i.ToString();
    string client_id = tx.ClientID;
    tx.Text = client_id;

    //script and key creation
    string key_for_javascript = "call" + i.ToString();
    string script_to_load = "call_me('" + client_id + "');";

    //add textbox to panel
    Panel1.Controls.Add(tx);

    //call script
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), key_for_javascript, script_to_load, true);

  }

}
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong or how I should fix this. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u try the following code.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            //textbox creation
            TextBox tx = new TextBox();
            tx.ID = "textbox" + i.ToString();
            string client_id = tx.ClientID;
            tx.Text = client_id;

            //script and key creation
            string key_for_javascript = "call" + i.ToString();
            string script_to_load = "call_me('" + client_id + "');";

            //add textbox to panel
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tx);

            //call script
         //   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), key_for_javascript, script_to_load, true);

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), key_for_javascript, script_to_load, true);

        }
```

Comment: Hi Ram bhai, I just tried it and it works perfect. Thank you. Would you mind explaining why this works to me please? I would really like to know. @Ramselvaraj

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock can be used for Updatepanel or Ajaxcontrol.